# Search function for a phonebook.java project

Tags: java, arrays, search

So I've been working on this project PhoneBook.java program for awhile. The program opens up a .txt file and imports it into a List sorted by Lastname, Firstname. I am attempting to write a search function that opens a window, asks you to input a name, then upon clicking ok it should select the searched index. I can not understand why my following code for the searchMI is not working. I appreciate any help you can give me.

```
public class PhoneBook extends Frame implements ActionListener, ItemListener {

MenuItem newMI, openMI, saveMI, saveAsMI, exitMI;
MenuItem searchMI, deleteMI, updateMI, newEntryMI, sortMI;
String fileName;
List nameList;
List numberList;
TextField lastName, firstName, phoneNumber;

// implementing ActionListener
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    Object source = event.getSource();
    if(source == newMI) 
    {
        nameList.removeAll();
        numberList.removeAll();
        fileName = null;
        display(-1);
        setTitle("White Pages")
    }
    else if(source == searchMI) 
    {
        String searchName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this,
                            "Please enter a name (last first) to search:");
        System.out.println("Name to search: " + searchName);
        int index = nameList.getSelectedIndex();
        String name = lastName.getText().trim() + " " + firstName.getText().trim();
            for(int i=0; i!=index; i++){
                if(nameList.equals(searchName)){
                    nameList.select(index);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Error searching for the name: " + searchName);
                }
        ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Suggestions

- Why this: `int index = nameList.getSelectedIndex();`? It does not look as if the selected index will give you any useful information here.
- This will never work: `if(nameList.equals(searchName)){`. A List cannot equal a String.
- Instead use your for loop, loop through whatever collection holds the Strings, I'm guessing it's the `nameList` and compare the String held at each item with the entered String.
- The for loop should go from `i = 0` to `i < nameList.getItemCount()` (or `nameList.size()` if it is a java.util.List).
- Don't have that else block, `else{ System.out.println("Error searching for the name: "...` inside of the for loop. Doing that will print out the else Statement many times.
- You're better off using the Swing library components not AWT.
- You'll want to format your posted code better. Each statement should have its own line. Careful and regular indentations matter.
- Since you are using components in your GUI, you may not need that JOptionPane. Could you instead get the search String from one of your text fields?

Comment: thank you Hovercraft I appreciate your response. Sorry about the formatting it is my first time posting.